# axisLabels are not show event majorTickLocations are set

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

After a lot of hours invested, I can't figure out what I'm missing.  I followed many examples related to custom labels, but I can't find the answer.  What could be wrong?  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Custom label defintion:

```
NSMutableArray *customArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[xcLabels count]];
int idx = 0;
for (NSNumber *tickLocation in  xcLabels) {  
    CPTAxisLabel *iLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[xcLabels objectAtIndex:idx++] textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
    iLabel.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromInt(idx);
    iLabel.offset       = x.labelOffset + x.majorTickLength;
    iLabel.rotation = M_PI/2;
    [customArray addObject:iLabel];
    [iLabel release];
}
x.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:customArray];
NSLog(@"x.axisLabels%@", x.axisLabels);
[customArray release];
```

majorTicklocation definition:

```
 NSMutableArray *ticks = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[xcLabels count]] autorelease];
for ( NSUInteger loc = 0; loc < [xcLabels count]; ++loc ) {
    [ticks addObject:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:loc]];}
NSLog(@"tickLocations%@", ticks);
x.majorTickLocations =[NSSet setWithArray:ticks];
NSLog(@"x.majorTickLocations%@", x.majorTickLocations);
```

Data defintion

```
- (void) xLabels {
xcLabels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[self.dataGraph count]];
for (int i = 0; i < [self.dataGraph count]; ++i) {
    NSNumber* nsValue = [self.dataGraph objectAtIndex:i];
    CGPoint point = [nsValue CGPointValue];
    NSLog(@"point.x%f", point.x);
    NSDate *xFecha = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:point.x];
    NSLog(@"xFecha%@", xFecha);
    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM"];
    NSString *nstFecha = [df stringFromDate:xFecha];
    [df release];
    [xcLabels addObject:nstFecha];}}
```

x.axisLabels output:

```
x.axisLabels{(
<<CPTAxisLabel: 0x6e7c250> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x6e7bf60> bounds: {{0, 0}, {35, 19}}> "14-01">}>,
<<CPTAxisLabel: 0x6e7c040> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x6e7da30> bounds: {{0, 0}, {35, 19}}> "28-01">}>,
<<CPTAxisLabel: 0x6e7dae0> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x6e7db10> bounds: {{0, 0}, {35, 19}}> "14-02">}>,
<<CPTAxisLabel: 0x6e7dbc0> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x6e7dbf0> bounds: {{0, 0}, {35, 19}}> "25-02">}>,
<<CPTAxisLabel: 0x6e7dca0> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x6e7dcd0> bounds: {{0, 0}, {35, 19}}> "14-03">}>,
<<CPTAxisLabel: 0x6e7dd80> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x6e7ddb0> bounds: {{0, 0}, {35, 19}}> "30-03">}>,
<<CPTAxisLabel: 0x6e7de60> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x6e7de90> bounds: {{0, 0}, {35, 19}}> "14-04">}>,
<<CPTAxisLabel: 0x6e7df40> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x6e7df70> bounds: {{0, 0}, {35, 19}}> "29-04">}>,
<<CPTAxisLabel: 0x6e7e020> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x6e7e050> bounds: {{0, 0}, {35, 19}}> "09-05">}>,
<<CPTAxisLabel: 0x6e7e100> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x6e7e190> bounds: {{0, 0}, {35, 19}}> "29-08">}>,
<<CPTAxisLabel: 0x6e7e200> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x6e7e230> bounds: {{0, 0}, {35, 19}}> "29-09">}>,
<<CPTAxisLabel: 0x6e7e2e0> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x6e7e370> bounds: {{0, 0}, {35, 19}}> "27-10">}>,
<<CPTAxisLabel: 0x6e7e3e0> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x6e7e410> bounds: {{0, 0}, {35, 19}}> "29-11">}>,
<<CPTAxisLabel: 0x6e7e4c0> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x6e7e550> bounds: {{0, 0}, {35, 19}}> "28-12">}>
```

)}

x.majorTickLocations output

```
2012-05-29 22:21:46.960 AbcPrpk[8931:fb03] x.majorTickLocations{(
0,
13,
12,
11,
7,
6,
2,
1,
10,
9,
8,
5,
4,
3
)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the `tickLocation` of all of the custom labels to zero (0). Increment `idx` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code in the above that tells me your labels are being added to the view tree (eg., [self addSubview:someLabel])

You can verify that is your problem by logging the value of the window property on any of your labels -- if it returns nil, then your views haven't been added to the view tree.

Comment: thanks for your response, but I check all the examples in core-plot and I can't find any "addSubView".  When you  set, I guess,  "x.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:customArray];", you`re adding the labels to the plot. I think that is more related to  bounds: {{0, 0}, but I don't have any benchmark to confirm my hypothesis

Comment: Ok, I haven't used CorePlot -- but I can tell you, if those labels inherit from UIView, and you're not seeing them on screen, you can still check their .window property and if its nil, it's because some code hasn't added them to the view tree.